# How to filter a date column that is in "INT" format

Tags: sql, hive, dbeaver, trino

I have a table with the date column being INT in the format
`"yyyy/MM/dd"`. I need to have two separate queries. The first one needs to pull data from the start of current year up to the current day and the second query needs to pull data from the previous year up to the corresponding day in the previous year.

e.g.

```
Query1 = (01 January 2023 to 15 November 2023)
Query2 = (01 January 2022 to 15 November 2022)
```

I tried

```
date_parse(cast(tbl_dt as varchar), '%Y%m%d') > date(current_date) - interval '365' day
```

but that takes the last 365 days.

I also tried where `tbl_dt> 20230101`, but that is essentially hard coded and I would need to change the query every year.

Comment: "column being INT in the format "yyyy/MM/dd"" - that's impossible, `int` can't contain slashes. Do you actually mean the format `yyyyMMdd`?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't change the column to use a date/datetime type?

Comment: Please add some sample data.

Comment: @Dai yes it is in that format yyyyMMdd. (e.g. 20230822)

Comment: @ZaahidMunshi That doesn't answer my question

Answer (score 3):

You could convert your filter dates into an INT, via a conversion to `112` date format, which is yyyyMMdd.

```
SELECT CAST(CONVERT(varchar(8), GETDATE(), 112) AS INT)
```

This would give you:

> 20231115

So, you could generate INTs to filter with, rather than convert every INT to a date to filter them.

Over the long term... you might want to add a new column with a date type, and start populating it / migrating the INT data into it. This gives you a path to move away from INTs without having to immediately stop using them right away.

To use this conversion in your query, your `WHERE` clause would be:

```
WHERE
    tbl_dt > CAST(CONVERT(varchar(8), @fromDate, 112) AS INT)
AND
    tbl_dt < CAST(CONVERT(varchar(8), @toDate, 112) AS INT)
```

This is *exclusive* of the two dates, not *inclusive*.